# Getting Liquibase error when trying to create a table in a H2 database

Tags: plugins, gradle, h2, liquibase, create-table

How do you use Liquibase to create a table in the H2 in-memory database?  I’m using Gradle 2.7, the Liquibase 1.1.1 plugin, and the H2 1.4.190 plugin.  Here’s my Liquibase create table statement …

```
    <changeSet author="davea" id="add_my_prefix_sync_address">
            <createTable tableName="my_prefix_sync_address">
        <column defaultValue="" name="id" type="VARCHAR(32)">
            <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true"/>
        </column>
        <column defaultValue="" name="address" type="VARCHAR(500)">
            <constraints nullable="true"/>
        </column>
        <column defaultValue="" name="city" type="VARCHAR(100)">
            <constraints nullable="true"/>
        </column>
        <column defaultValue="" name="state" type="VARCHAR(10)">
            <constraints nullable="true"/>
        </column>
        <column defaultValue="" name="zip" type="VARCHAR(10)">
            <constraints nullable="true"/>
        </column>
        <column defaultValue="" name="lattitude" type="INT UNSIGNED">
            <constraints nullable="true"/>
        </column>
        <column defaultValue="" name="longitude" type="INT UNSIGNED">
            <constraints nullable="true"/>
        </column>
        <column defaultValue="" name="email" type="VARCHAR(200)">
            <constraints nullable="true"/>
        </column>
        <column defaultValue="" name="phone" type="VARCHAR(32)">
            <constraints nullable="true"/>
        </column>
        <column defaultValue="" name="phone_type" type="VARCHAR(10)">
            <constraints nullable="true"/>
        </column>
            </createTable>
    </changeSet>
```

but upon running my Grade build command, I get this error …

```
Execution failed for task ':update'.
> liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: Unexpected error running Liquibase: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.my_prefix_SYNC_ADDRESS (ID VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, ADDRESS VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT '', CITY VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '', STATE VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT '', ZIP VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT '', LATTITUDE INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT ,[*] LONGITUDE INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT , EMAIL VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT '', PHONE VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT '', PHONE_TYPE VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT '', CONSTRAINT PK_my_prefix_SYNC_ADDRESS PRIMARY KEY (ID)) "; expected "NOT, EXISTS, INTERSECTS, SELECT, FROM"; SQL statement:
  CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.my_prefix_sync_address (id VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, address VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT '', city VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '', state VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT '', zip VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT '', lattitude INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT , longitude INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT , email VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT '', phone VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT '', phone_type VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT '', CONSTRAINT PK_my_prefix_SYNC_ADDRESS PRIMARY KEY (id)) [42001-190]
```

If it matters, these are the plugins I have set up in my build.grade script …

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.36'
    classpath 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.190'
    classpath 'org.flywaydb:flyway-gradle-plugin:3.2.1'
  }
}

…
plugins {
  id "org.liquibase.gradle" version "1.1.1"
}

…

flyway {
    url = 'jdbc:h2:mem:test'
    user = 'sa'
}

liquibase {
  activities {
    main {
      File propsFile = new File(liquibasePropertiesFile)
      Properties properties = new Properties()
      properties.load(new FileInputStream(propsFile))
      changeLogFile 'src/main/resources/db.changelog-master.xml'
      url properties['url']
      username properties['username']
      password properties['password']
    }
    test {
      File propsFile = new File(liquibasePropertiesFile)
      Properties properties = new Properties()
      properties.load(new FileInputStream(propsFile))
      changeLogFile 'src/main/resources/db.changelog-master.xml'
        url 'jdbc:h2:mem:test'
        username 'sa'
    }
    runList = 'main,test'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is not legal to use a varchar(32) column as a primary key.

Comment: Are you asking me or telling me?  Nothing in the documentation about such a restriction.

Comment: I don't know the details of H2, so it was a suggestion. I would try running the SQL generated in some other SQL tool and see what H2 says about it.

Comment: Running that SQL in H2 produces the same result.  My question is what changes do I need to make to my Liquibase changeSet or a configuration in my Gradle/H2 generation to get the changeSet to process properly.

Comment: If you can provide what the correct SQL is, that could be the basis for a bug report.

Comment: What was happening was having 'defaultValue=""' for a numeric column (<column defaultValue="" name="lattitude" type="INT UNSIGNED">) was causing the SQL to be generated as "DEFAULTVALUE ," (for a String it would be "DEFAULTVALUE ''").  Not sure if this is a Liquibase bug but easy enough to clean up in the script.